# dplyr reset counter when the threshold is reached

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have following `tibble` called `test`:

```
  datetime                volume
  <dttm>                   <dbl>
  2020-08-25 09:30:00.000      0
  2020-08-25 09:30:12.000    107
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    221
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    132
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    148
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:30:58.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:31:56.000    157
  2020-08-25 09:32:36.000    288
  2020-08-25 09:32:36.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:33:10.000    235
  2020-08-25 09:33:23.000    182
  2020-08-25 09:33:44.000    218
  2020-08-25 09:33:44.000    179
  2020-08-25 09:34:18.000    318
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    101
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    157
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    200
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    114
```

I wanted to calculate the cumulative time difference (or even the just the number of rows where the timestamps are the same) when a threshold for the `volume` is reached. Once the threshold is reached/surpassed, I reset the counter to 0, and accumulate from that point onward again.

For example, if my `threshold` is 300, I accumulate from row `1` to row `3`, I'd get `0+107+221=328`, I would now choose to:

- retain the timestamp of this row,
- calculate the time difference from row `1` to row `3`,
- or count the number of rows till I reached the threshold

any of above would serve the purpose, best option would be retaining the timestamp.

Next step is to reset the counter (which at the moment stays at `328`) and start counting again from row `4`; from row `4` to row `7` I accumulate `148+100+100=348`, I'd retain the timestamp again (for example). I'd then again, reset the counter and move on again.

I was trying to do this with `dplyr` or generally in `tidyverse` however I wasn't able to come up with reasonable solution. I don't think there's a way to do this just solely piping-along-with-dplyr.

I think I can get by with a `for-loop` but that'd my last option. The difficult part for me is to reset the counter and start counting again.

Comment: Please add your desired output.

Comment: @tmfmnk sorry I can’t really come up with an ideal output as I am not sure what the final output would be. More importantly I think it’s easier to solve if there are alternatives because I think this one isn’t an easy one. I hope my description is clear enough, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group_id = cumsum(c(0, diff(accumulate(volume, ~ if_else(.x >= 300, .y, .x + .y))) < 0))) %>%
 summarise(timestamp_first = first(datetime),
           timestamp_last = last(datetime),
           time_diff = last(datetime) - first(datetime),
           n_rows = n(),
           volume_sum = sum(volume))

  group_id timestamp_first     timestamp_last      time_diff n_rows volume_sum
     <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>     <int>      <int>
1        0 2020-08-25 09:30:00 2020-08-25 09:30:50 50 secs        3        328
2        1 2020-08-25 09:30:50 2020-08-25 09:30:50  0 secs        3        380
3        2 2020-08-25 09:30:50 2020-08-25 09:31:56 66 secs        3        357
4        3 2020-08-25 09:32:36 2020-08-25 09:32:36  0 secs        2        388
5        4 2020-08-25 09:33:10 2020-08-25 09:33:23 13 secs        2        417
6        5 2020-08-25 09:33:44 2020-08-25 09:33:44  0 secs        2        397
7        6 2020-08-25 09:34:18 2020-08-25 09:34:18  0 secs        1        318
8        7 2020-08-25 09:34:27 2020-08-25 09:34:27  0 secs        3        458
9        8 2020-08-25 09:34:27 2020-08-25 09:34:27  0 secs        1        114
```

Comment: uhh....it’s very hard for me not to accept your answer now as it covered all alternatives hehe; the grouping isn’t very intuitive but I think I’ll take one bite at a time. I’ve learned new tricks today, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably get you going. It makes use of the `MESS`-package, especially the genius `cumsumbinning`-function.

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )
library( MESS )
test <- data.table::fread( "datetime                volume
2020-08-25T09:30:00.000      0
2020-08-25T09:30:12.000    107
2020-08-25T09:30:50.000    221
2020-08-25T09:30:50.000    132
2020-08-25T09:30:50.000    148
2020-08-25T09:30:50.000    100
2020-08-25T09:30:50.000    100
2020-08-25T09:30:58.000    100
2020-08-25T09:31:56.000    157
2020-08-25T09:32:36.000    288
2020-08-25T09:32:36.000    100
2020-08-25T09:33:10.000    235
2020-08-25T09:33:23.000    182
2020-08-25T09:33:44.000    218
2020-08-25T09:33:44.000    179
2020-08-25T09:34:18.000    318
2020-08-25T09:34:27.000    101
2020-08-25T09:34:27.000    157
2020-08-25T09:34:27.000    200
2020-08-25T09:34:27.000    114")

test[, datetime := as.POSIXct( datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS") ]
```

**code**

is in `data.table` syntax, but can easily be integreted in any tidyverse or baseR solution

```
#create groups based on cumsum with threshold of 300
test[, group_id := MESS::cumsumbinning( volume, threshold = 300, cutwhenpassed = TRUE )]

#                datetime volume group_id
#  1: 2020-08-25 09:30:00      0        1
#  2: 2020-08-25 09:30:12    107        1
#  3: 2020-08-25 09:30:50    221        1
#  4: 2020-08-25 09:30:50    132        2
#  5: 2020-08-25 09:30:50    148        2
#  6: 2020-08-25 09:30:50    100        2
#  7: 2020-08-25 09:30:50    100        3
#  8: 2020-08-25 09:30:58    100        3
#  9: 2020-08-25 09:31:56    157        3
# 10: 2020-08-25 09:32:36    288        4
# 11: 2020-08-25 09:32:36    100        4
# 12: 2020-08-25 09:33:10    235        5
# 13: 2020-08-25 09:33:23    182        5
# 14: 2020-08-25 09:33:44    218        6
# 15: 2020-08-25 09:33:44    179        6
# 16: 2020-08-25 09:34:18    318        7
# 17: 2020-08-25 09:34:27    101        8
# 18: 2020-08-25 09:34:27    157        8
# 19: 2020-08-25 09:34:27    200        8
# 20: 2020-08-25 09:34:27    114        9
```

Now the grouping is done, and summarising should be easy peasy..

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, this `cumsumbinning` is indeed genius, it’s very intuitive what it is doing from the code. And yes it’d be just usual work to get what I wanted thereon. Choosing between your answer and tmfmnk’s is real problem for me here!